# Binding converter to factory of converters

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to find a way to bind a converter to a property that returns a converter.

My code looks like this.

I have a class.

```
public class ConverterFactory 
  {
    public IValueConverter AuthorizationToEnabledConverter
        {
            get
            {
                return converter......
            }
        }
  }
```

I have a `UserControl` with resources and a button.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:ConverterFactory x:Key="ConverterFactory" b:IsDataSource="true"/>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AutCon"  ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ConverterFactory}"       
           MethodName="AuthorizationToEnabledConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding "Value" ,Converter={StaticResource AutCon}}" >Change</Button>
```

I want to be able to bind my converter to a property in some class that returns a `IValueConverter`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? maybe their is a different, simplier way to do this

Comment: whats the purpose of the factory?

Comment: The purpose of the factory is that I whant a Class with all of my converters. Some of the converters have injectionpoints that are resolved with unity. I can't get the ctor injection to work with xaml so I made a factory for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Binding b = new Binding("AuthorizationToEnabledConverter") { Source = this.FindResource("ConverterFactory")};
this.SetBinding(YourProperty, b);
```

Or via XAML:

```
YourProperty="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConverterFactory}, Path="AuthorizationToEnabledConverter"}"
```

EDIT: You can't bind the `Converter`-property of a binding because it's no `DependencyProperty`. An alternative way would be to create a custom `MarkupExtension` like so:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(IValueConverter))]
public class ConverterDispenser:MarkupExtension
{
    public IValueConverter MainConverter
    {
        get { return new TestConverter();}
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //with the help of serviceProvider you can get information about the surrounding elements and maybe decide depending on those information which converter to return.
        return MainConverter;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Source, Converter={local:ConverterDispenser}}""></TextBox>
```

Another alternative would be to implement your own `Binding` by deriving from `Binding`, and then adding a new DependencyProperty for your converter. Now you create a ValueChangedCallback for this property and everytime it changes, you set the original converter.

Comment: I can't get that to work..  I have a property like this:

  IsEnabled="{Binding "Value", Converter="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConterterFactory}, Path="AuthorizationToEnabledConverter"}"}"  

So it's the converter that shall be bound to this class

Comment: @user2806381 `Converter` isn't a `DependencyProperty`. That's why you can't set any binding on a `Converter`property. Have a look at my edit for an alternative.

Comment: @user2806381 If it solved your problem, please mark this one as answer. ;)